# Código while não faz a condição correta

Tags: c, c++, while

Eu preciso criar um código que leia apenas um `double` e registre em duas variáveis o "menor até agora" e o "maior até agora", eu até consigo completar um ciclo com sucesso mas depois disso ele imprime qualquer valor que eu inserir.

Tentei algumas maneiras como fazer uma função, voltar pro *looping* mas iria ficar defeituoso.

```
while(cin>>num1){
    cout << "maior ate agora " << num1 << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    if(num2 > num1)
        cout << "maior ate agora " << num2;
    else
        cout << "maior ate agora " << num1;
}
```

Comment: Coloque o resto do código para ver se tem erro em algum outro lugar. Outra coisa. Quando deve parar de perguntar? Aí não tem fim.

Comment: É basicamente isso, a não ser a declaração,  double entrada = 0;
    double menor = 0;
    double maior = 0;

Comment: E se o erro estiver nela?

Comment: Ya, eu editei a uns seg atrás :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas e o maior deles é que a comparação está sendo feito sempre com o primeiro número e não com o maior até agora. Outro problema sério é não ter uma forma de saída. Eu mudei para que um número negativo gere a saída. Pode ser modificado para outro critério caso queira aceitar negativos.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int maior = 0, numero = 0;
    while (numero >= 0) {
        cin >> numero;
        if (numero > maior) {
            maior = numero;
            cout << "maior ate agora " << maior << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/T05wbn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pjpquyum-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/LoopExit.cpp).

Comment: Eu sabia que era algo assim, tentei fazer algumas ideias de atribuições mas não deu certo, btw, valeu ^^

Answer (score 1):

A comparação está sendo feita de forma errada, pois sempre compara com o primeiro. Mude o seu `while`:

```
while (num1 >= 0) {
   cin >> num1;
   if(num1 > maior) {
      maior = num1;
      cout << "maior ate agora " << maior << endl;
   }
}
```